# OAuth2 bearer token refresh strategy

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0

I just made my own OAuth2 server using Node.js and `node-oauth2-server` library, and following this [tutorial](https://blog.cloudboost.io/how-to-make-an-oauth-2-server-with-node-js-a6db02dc2ce7).

The question at this point after implementing such authentication system is this.

Ok. Now I can store the Bearer token in Client-side and the users won't have to log in every time, neither will I have to store their credentials.

However, I am still storing the Bearer token, when stolen, will grant anyone the same access to the token's original owner.

What strategies can I take now so that I can enforce the below rules:

1. Logged in users don't have to re-login unless they logout themselves
2. Bearer tokens (stored on both server&client-sides are constantly refreshed to discourage hackers)
3. Detect and handle the situation when a user's bearer token is compromised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some rules you must follow to make sure that no malicious JavaScript can access your tokens:

1. Serve all pages over HTTPS.
2. Don't use a CDN or any other untrusted domain to load javascript, css or other content. If you do, that content can access localStorage or cookies.
3. When rendering dynamic content that was generated by user input, always implement [XSS escaping](https://www.google.com/search?q=XSS+escaping+react+angular) which prevents user content from loading new scripts. This is enabled by default in Angular and React.js.